# d3.js: tickformat - adding a % sign without multiplying by 100

Tags: formatting, d3.js

my data has percents as, for example, `[10.1, 3.2, 5.4]`

`d3.format("0f")` will give me `[10, 3, 5]`

`d3.format("0%")` will give me `[1010%, 320%, 540%]` (multiplies by 100)

how do I get `[10%, 3%, 5%]`?

I can't figure out where to add a +"%" to the first case
or eliminate the *100 in the second case

the relevant parts of the code:

```
var formatPercent = d3.format("0f");

var min = 0; 
var max = d3.max(data, function(d) { return + d[5]; });
max = Math.round(max * 1.2); // pad it

//define the x-axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .orient('top')
                .ticks(6)
                .tickFormat(formatPercent);
```

and data comes in like this:

```
{
    "Geography": [
    ["Midwest", 234017797, 498, 8.2, 9.0, 11.3],
    ["Northeast", 265972035, 566, 8.9, 12.1, 13.1],
    ["South", 246235593, 524, 8.1, 8.3, 10.8],
    ["West", 362774577, 772, 9.4,9.9, 11.7]
    ]
}
```

It's the last three numbers in each line that are the percentage values I'm using to chart ranges. I want the x-axis to be formatted in integer+% format based on the high and low values in the data.

Thank you!

Comment: can you please post a little bit more of the code interested?

Comment: @tomtomtom I've added further details from the code. I realize I could probably just manipulate the data for max & min to get around this, but I do want to know how to simply add a percent sign.

Comment: var formatPercent = function (d) {return d3.format("0f") + "%"}
maybe can do the trick, but i'm not that sure

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**Update for D3 v4 (using ES6):**

```
// Can also be axisTop, axisRight, or axisBottom
d3.axisLeft()
    .tickFormat(d => d + "%")
```

**Original answer for D3 v3:**

You can create your own format:

```
d3.svg.axis()
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return d + "%"; });
```

If you want to get rid of the decimal places:

```
d3.svg.axis()
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return parseInt(d, 10) + "%"; });
```

Comment: Needed to multiply the values, works fine: `.tickFormat(d => (parseInt(d.toString()) * this.resolution).toString());`