# Error using d3.format in d3-legend when upgrading from D3 v3 to v5

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm in the process of upgrading a visualisation from D3 v3 to v5.

I've been using [d3-legend](https://d3-legend.susielu.com/) to draw the legend, so I've also changed which version of d3-legend I'm using, from v1.13.0 (the latest version compatible with D3 v3) to v2.25.6.

I previously used `d3.format` together with d3-legend's `labelFormat` to format the legend text labels - applying different formatting depending which dataset had been loaded. The code which was working for me in D3 v3 isn't working for me in v5 and I can't figure out why.

My code (D3 v5 version):

```
var value = 'ks4prog'

var quantize=d3.scaleQuantize()

quantize.domain([-0.8,0.8])
    .range(["rgb(230,0,126)", "rgb(207,21,138)","rgb(184,43,151)"])

d3.legendColor()
    .shapeWidth(30)
    .orient('vertical')
    .scale(quantize)
    .labelFormat(function(d) {
        if (value=="ks2att" || value=="ks4basics") {
            return d3.format(".0f")(d) + "%";
        }
        else {
            return d3.format(".1f")(d);
        }
    });
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: invalid format: function(d) {
        if (value=="ks2att" || value=="ks4basics") {
            return d3.format(".0f")(d) + "%";
        }
        else {
            return d3.format(".1f")(d);
        }
    }
    at new FormatSpecifier (d3-format.js:111)
    at formatSpecifier (d3-format.js:107)
    at Function.legend.labelFormat (color.js:233)
    at collapsibletree_edited.js:12
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474620/d3-js-tickformat-adding-a-sign-without-multiplying-by-100) led me to think I might need to change the format of the function I use to set `.labelFormat` - but I can't figure out how, in a case like mine where I'm setting `.labelFormat` conditionally.

Comment: From the docs it looks like `labelFormat` only takes a d3.format object or a format string, not a function. Looks like it is trying to use your function as a format string and that's what breaks. I'm not sure what the solution is but thought I'd point that out.

Comment: @Gordon Thanks, I see what you mean. I guess being able to use a function in `labelFormat` was maybe undocumented functionality available in the earlier version of d3-legend. I guess I can probably get around it using a formulation like the following - editing my source data first so that I can use `d3.format`'s percentage formatting:
```if (value=="ks2att" || value=="ks4basics") {
 legend.labelFormat(d3.format(".0%"))
}
else {
 legend.labelFormat(d3.format(".1f"))
}
```

Comment: Oh that's nice. I didn't see that the choice of formatting depended on an external variable, not the data itself. That's a great solution, and more efficient fwiw.